# Switching the plot variable when plotting a two-variable function as a single variable function with a parameter

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I would like to make easy to change the variable for which I am making a set of plots. Say I want to plot Sin, Tan, Cos and other functions of the same argument. To quickly switch from plotting it as function of x or y I wanted to use a "dummy" plot variable var and assing it to y or x depending on the need.

```
x = 1; var = y;
Plot[Sin[x*y], {var, 1, 2}]
Plot[Tan[x*y], {var, 1, 2}]
Plot[Cos[x*y], {var, 1, 2}]
Unset[{x, y, var}];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't quite works because `var` in the range specification `{var,1,2}` is not evaluated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Evaluate@{var, 1, 2}`...

Comment: great! it works, but what is the difference with respect to `Evaluate[var]` which was my trial before posting here?

Comment: I can't check it but as far as I remember `Evaluate` works only on first level.

Answer (score 2):

You need to force evaluation of the x interval list:

```
x = 8; var = y;
Plot[Sin[x*y], Evaluate@{var, 1, 2}]
Plot[Tan[x*y], Evaluate@{var, 1, 2}]
Plot[Cos[x*y], Evaluate@{var, 1, 2}]
Unset[{x, y, var}];
```

[image: plots]